# iPhone - What is the size of UIslider's thumb?

Tags: iphone, uislider

I am using the UISlider's setThumbImage:forState to customize the look of slider's thumb.
But this looks much bigger. The image that I'm using is of size 55x55 pixels.
What should be the size of image that i've to use?

Comment: maybe take a look at this post.. http://stackoverflow.com/questions/755510/customizing-uislider-look

Answer (score 10, accepted):

From XIB, i found that, the height of UISlider is 23 pixels. And when I changed the image size to 23x23 pixels, it looks perfect now.