# Creating half circular knob in ios sdk

Tags: ios5

How to create a circular knob when user swipes it should rotate that much.

It should rotate on touch.

Its like a radio tuner.

http://db.tt/D8gj4H9G

what should be the right approach doing this?

Can any body please guide on the right path.

Comment: if its a full circular disk it easy to rotate CGAffineTransformMakeRotation(angleRadians), but this is arc only what could be the approach I am still thinking.Any help ?

Comment: Did you get any of the kind? If yes, please give me too.

Answer (score 0):

It seems like the easiest way to accomplish this would be to use the UISlider. No?

See: [Change iPhone UISlider bar image](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2379326/change-iphone-uislider-bar-image) or
[Customizing UISlider look](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/755510/customizing-uislider-look)

Otherwise you could do an image animation on the button, as in this example: http://iosdevelopertips.com/graphics/animated-gif-animated-images-iphone-style.html

Comment: thanks Dan but that would not give a real look and feel to this component